# Echo wordpress insert post mysql query along with any taxonomy details

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How may I echo the last Insert New Post Query showing the mysql query used with all the post details and also the taxonomies and categories/ mysql queries for these if they are inserted separately from the above query?

I'd like to know the structure of the query so I may bulk insert posts which I have from a csv file.

Comment: Please post some code that you have created, so you can be helped.

Comment: Well, that kinda is the problem. I don't know where to put the echo statement. I can't seem to isolate where WP does the Insert and also how the taxonomy tables are affected when an insert is made.